# AngularJS routing with ng-view relative to HTML page

Tags: angularjs, url, routes

I am quite new to Angular and now trying to make a simple routing with it. I have my landing page, currently called index2.html, containing some .js and .css includes and a div containing `<ng-view></ng-view>` where my content should go into.
My app.js looks like this:

```
var module1 = angular.module('module1', ['ngRoute']);

module1.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
  $routeProvider.when("/",
    {
      templateUrl: "page1.html",
      controller: "uiCtrl"
    }
    ).when("/:param",
    {
      templateUrl: "page1.html",
      controller: "uiCtrl"
    }
    ).when("/transactions",
    {
      templateUrl: "page2.html",
      controller: "uiCtrl"
    });
});
```

But actually this does quite confusing things. Calling http://myurl.com/index2.html, the content of page1.html is properly loaded into the ng-view. So far, so good, but calling index2.html/123 gives my a Not Found instead of interpreting 123 as a parameter. I don't know why, but to make 123 a paremeter i have to call index2.html#123, which works, but then instantly updates the url to index2.html#/123.
Calling index2.html/transactions doesn't work at all. How can i call my /transactions route?

EDIT: If this is useful, i am using JQueryMobile as well in these pages.

Comment: Looks like it should be `index2.html#/123` since you are not using HTML5 route mode.

Comment: What exactly does that html5 mode? And how can i achieve that i can call index2.html/transaction (or sth. similar) to view my transactions-page inside the ng-view?

Comment: If you use html5Mode then you need to configure webserver to respond with `index2.html` for all requests (excepts static of course, images, css, etc.). Otherwise you have to use hashbang mode and use `index2.html#/transaction`.

Comment: is it possible to remove index2.html from the url? by setting it as welcome page. then your url will be simple, you can type myurl.com for index2.html and myurl.com/123 for index2.html#/123

Answer (score 0):

I finally got what I want by getting the HTML5 mode work, which makes things so much easier.
After setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` I had to re-configure my webserver, what I wasn't able to manage until I found this nice guide: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Now I can access each of my routes at the conventional way using a slash. Parameters can be passed with `?` and `&`, as usual and I don't need to grapple with confusing hashtags and self-changing url's anymore.